# Update select tag in MySQL by laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

**Hello my masters,**

I want to update (link_name, link_address, link_type). Link_type with tag in HTML page feed. I know many code exist in internet about CURD but I don’t know why my code don’t execute correctly. There is some problem that I mention in following, maybe long so first of all apologize.

**First part: fetching data from DB with Ajax.  In editlink.blade.php**

```
try {
    for(var count=0; count < data.length; count++)
    {
   html +='<tr >';
   html +='<td contenteditable class="column_name" data-column_name="link_name" data-id="'+data[count].id+'">'+data[count].name+'</td>';
        html += '<td contenteditable class="column_name" data-column_name="link_add" data-id="'+data[count].id+'">'+data[count].Address+'</td>';
        html += '<td contenteditable class="column_name" data-column_name="link_type"    data-id="'+data[count].id+'">' +
                    '<select id="opttypes"  value="'+data[count].id+'">' +
                        '<option id="opt1"'+ check_selected1(data[count].type)+' value="1"'+' >'+d1+'</option>' +
                        '<option id="opt2"'+  check_selected2(data[count].type)+' value="2"'+' >'+d2+'</option>' +
                        '<option id="opt3"'+  check_selected3(data[count].type)+' value="3"'+' >'+d3+'</option>' +
                        '<option id="opt4"'+ check_selected4(data[count].type)+' value="4"'+' >'+d4+'</option>' +
                    '</select>' +
               '</td>';
        html += '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete" id="'+data[count].id+'">Delete</button>' +
            '<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs edite" id="'+data[count].id+"_"+count+'">Update</button></td></tr>';
    }
    $('tbody').html(html);
}// end try
catch (e) {

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "error accrue in fetch form DB ";

}
```

**Description first part:**

1) Data is backed variable from Ajax, that include weblinks table in DB.
2) Spread count in edit button use to refer row in table and then fetch content of cell.

**Second part: java code of edit button in editlink.blad.php**

```
$(document).on('click', '.edite', function(){
    var allid=$(this).attr("id").split("_");// try to access id of data and number of row in HTML table
    var id2=allid[0];// fetch ID of data in DB
    var countRow=Number(allid[1])+2;// calculate detected row that user clicked.
    var link_name = document.getElementById("html_table").rows[countRow].cells.item(0);// gets links name
    var link_add =document.getElementById("html_table").rows[countRow].cells.item(1);// gets link address
        var link_type=$("#link_type :selected").val();// gets which option user clicked.
        if(link_name != '' && link_add != '' && link_type!='' )
    {

        if(!confirm("Do you want to edit this row")) {
            return false;
        }

            try
            {
                $.ajax({
                    url:"{{ route('weblink.update_data') }}",
                    method:"POST",
                    data:{link_name:link_name, link_add:link_add, link_type2:link_type, id:id, _token:_token},
                    success: function(data){ // What to do if we succeed
                        if(data == "success")
                            $('#message').html(data);
                        },
                    error: function(data){
                        alert('Error'+data);
                    }
                })
            }
            catch (e) {
                $('#message').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>error in receiving data from Ajax   </div>");

            }
    }// end if check empty box
    else {
        $('#message').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>Both Fields are required</div>");
    }

});
```

**Description this part**

1)  When I click update button option tag showed -1 that refer the first option which isn’t useful. I use this code for add button work correctly but I don’t know why in this function doesn’t work.

**Third part: Function in controller**

```
 function update_data(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax())
    {
              weblink::where('id', $request->id)->update([
             'name' => '$request->link_name',
             'Address'=>'$request->link_add',
        type=>'$request->link_type2'


        ]);
                echo '<div class="alert alert-success">Data Updated</div>';
    }
}
```

**Description this part**

1)  Weblink is model

**Fourth part: web.php for update**

```
Route::post('/weblink/update_data', 'weblinksController@update_data')->name('weblink.update_data');
```

Excuse me every one, I know my code is boring. If possible help me.If every one like please give me your mail I will send all of my code completely(View, Controller and web).

Best regards.

Comment: Out of the 4 parts you've shared, which specific part is not exactly working as you expect? Is there an error message you're receiving we could look at?

Comment: I think java code that generate data and send to Ajax doesn't work correctly. I send all of file completely to you. Maybe check by yourself clear my issue. Thanks

Comment: Ok that's a great clue. The next thing I'd do if I were in your shoes, would be to trace down the JavaScript snippet line by line to figure out which specific line is not producing the result I expect.

For example, if you're suspecting that the ajax call is the issue, you may want to `console.log({link_name:link_name, link_add:link_add, link_type2:link_type, id:id, _token:_token})` just before the ajax call to see if the data you're passing is exactly structured as you expect.

I'd personally repeat that with every line I suspect until I boil the problem down to 1 specific line/error.

Comment: your  advice same as lamp on dark road light my insight. thanks.